# add Gson element in the correct place to file on disk 

Tags: java, json, gson

my question is this: I need to add an element in an array Gson saved to a file on disk. Explaining: I add an object of type DirectoryMap in a ArrayList, convert it to JSON (using Gson) and saved to disk. After that, I need to add another element to the ArrayList and resave the file. When I do that, I wait for something like this: [{object1},{object2},{object3}]

But I got it here:
[{object1}][{object2}]

Can anyone tell me how can I add a new object GSON to the file to disk so that the structure remains correct?

thanks.

Comment: Could you show how you append you second object?